# How to patch bootstrap in NAND flash?

Tags: patching, memory-dump, flash

I read the layout or my NAND  flash and saw that in the beginning of flash there is a bootstrap the the CPU load. That flash has ECC

I read/write that flash.

How can I analyze the bootstrap and change value there without demege the ECC?